# Find a sequence in another sequence

Tags: algorithm, vector

I want to write an algorithm that searches a sequence in another sorted sequence

Comment: That "don't intersect". Surely 1 & 4 don't intersect either? How did [_your_ first attempt go?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about intersection?

Comment: if you will draw a line between numbers from b in a,the line for each number will not intersect.

Comment: For example: 3 from b is at index 2(index starts from 0)in a,but 5 witch is before 3 has the index 4 in a.This means that the lines will intersect.Do you understand?

Comment: I'm afraid I still can't understand what you mean. I drew diagrams of my best guesses as to what you might be describing, but I still don't understand what lines you are talking about intersecting: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-JdBfe2tpx-w/UJ_xDvEWwuI/AAAAAAAADhM/mXjKe21mjc8/s640/numberlines.png Are the lines between items in each list, like my figure A? Or back and forth in the one list, like B? What counts as an intersection?

Comment: you drew correct in column A.If you see the red lines intersected.I need an algorithm that generate my pairs of number that don't have that red line intersected.If you will draw only the line for 5 and 7 from b to a,you will see that the line witch associate 5 from b to a and 7 from b and a,don't intersect.Moreover,{3,4,7} can be other pair that fills.another can be {1,4,6}.Every pair drew separate will  not have the red lines that you put intersect.

Comment: This smells like a potentially interesting question, but the explanation as it stands is awful. There is no such thing as a straight number, and it's quite unclear what "they don't intersect" means or refers to. Can you maybe start with a smaller example, and explain how YOU identified that the output was 5,7? And why any of the 5 other numbers don't work?

Comment: http://s18.postimage.org/evl64plhl/111120121813.jpg    it's ok now?

Comment: there can be a lot of a solution,but i need only one of all

Comment: Okay, you've given enough information here in the comments so that I understand why "5 7" is an acceptable answer, but it also seems that "3 4 7", "2 4 6", "3", "6" or even an empty sequence would also meet these criteria, i.e. any increasing subsequence of b. Can you give some idea of how to pick between these for the algorithm's output? Or do you want all of them? Also, you should definitely edit the question to clarify this, so that others don't need to search through the comments.

Comment: Only a pair which has the maxim elements that fill the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pair of lines associated with two number can only cross if those numbers appear in opposite orders in *a* and *b*. Since you state that the first list - *a* - is sorted (in increasing order) we will only have lines crossing if we pick numbers that are in *de*-creasing order in *b*.

You state in the comments that you want to pick the *maximum* number of elements that fulfil the criteria. (I'm a bit confused, as in your example, you select "5 7", but you also point out longer sequences that also meet the criteria. I'm going to assume that you do in fact require a longest sequence, such as "3 4 7".) So you need to find the maximum increasing subsequence of *b*. This is a well-studied problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#Efficient_algorithms

Comment: I need the pair with maxim elements starting with the first element from b.For this reason I put the pair {5,7}.Thanks a lot fr your answers!